# Orchard About us Page in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, orchardcms-1.8

I am new to Orchard CMS. I have created an About-Us page from the admin Dashboard.
Now, I want to put javascript on About-Us page only. Kindly tell me where can I find the About-Us page in solution explorer of Visual Studio? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

PS: I am using Orchard 1.8.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think, i quite get it. 
here is the view for the dashboard: `\Orchard.Web\Core\Dashboard\Views\Admin\Index.cshtml`
Adding javascript to any view is done by using `Script.Include([PathToResource])` or `Script.Require([NameOfResource])` and/or `@using (Script.Foot()) { [InlineJavascript]}`
If what you are asking is, How to add javascript to a page created with the `Page Content Type` then you need to add `Parts` to your `ContentType`. 
A good start will be [Vandelay.Industries 1.8](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Vandelay.Industries) (the latest), but there are others. 
Enjoy!